How to configure/update the messaging endpoint for an Azure Bot Service?
I have an Azure Bot Service, and I'm looking for an API or SDK option that allows me to change the messaging endpoint without manually going through the Azure Portal or using the CLI.
Is there a specific API or SDK that I can use for this purpose? If so, could someone provide an example of how to achieve this?
Any guidance would be appreciated! Thank you very much.
For context, I am creating a service that allow users to onboard their independent Azure bot and I would like to assign different endpoint for each of the bots. I am using nodejs bot framework SDK - botbuilder-js for all the activity event handling.

Yes. You can do it easily with the Az CLI. There is an example and more info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-bot-update
I also use it regularly in a Powershell script I use (using Az Powershell module). Here's a snippet:
$bot = Get-AzBotService -Name 'MyBestBot' -ResourceGroupName 'Bots'
Update-AzBotService -InputObject $bot -Endpoint 'https://mynewendpoint/api/messages' | Out-Null



Hi there, thanks for answering. I do know that this can be achieved via the CLI, but I would like to achieve this using API or SDK. :-)

Apologies. Didn't read close enough. I haven't done it, but you should be able to use the botservice write operation:
https://resources.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.BotService/operations
If needed, you might also be able to determine more info by finding out how the CLI does it when it itself uses the REST API:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/capturing-powershell-and-az-cli-rest-api-calls/ba-p/3960926

Sorry, it would just be a PUT operation with the new endpoint info. https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<Subscription>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/<BOT>?api-version=2018-07-12
 "properties": { "endpoint": "https://mynewendpoint.com/api/messages"}
Not sure what the entire payload needs to look like.
